# How to remove duplicate slashes from URL in Next Js.How to intercept and modify a request on the server side getServerSideProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, next.js

How to intercept and modify a request on the server side?

> http://localhost//example///author/admin///

should be

> http://localhost/example/author/admin/

How to remove duplicate slashes from URL in Next Js.How to intercept and modify a request on the server side с помощью getServerSideProps?

```
   export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
```

return {
redirect: {
permanent: false,
destination: context.req.replace(/([^:])(//+)/g, '$1/'),
},
};
};

Comment: why do you have those slashes in the first place?

Comment: An easy solution would be doing it in two steps: first replace all multiple slashes with a single one, then add back the second slash after 'http': `router.asPath.replace(/\/{2,}/g, '/').replace(/(https?:\/)/, '$1/');`

Comment: So that if you enter incorrectly (add. ///), the user will still go to the address

Comment: With useEffect, first there is a transition to 404 and then a redirect without unnecessary slashes. And how to make sure that there is no transition to 404 at all.

Comment: `useEffect()` hook is executed *after* the first render; that is why you have the first 404 error. If you want to avoid that, I think you have to intercept and modify the request on server side.

Comment: How to intercept and modify a request on the server side?

Comment: Well technically its users' fault if they enter a wrong URL, but if you want this, you can create a file `[...slug].js` file alongside index, and use `getServerSideProps` there. It will have access to `req` object.

Comment: Can getServerSideProps be used in root .js? That would immediately go to all pages

Comment: @Александр What exactly is `root.js`? There is no such file in Next.js present by default.

Comment: How to write the code correctly using getServerSideProps to replace extra slashes in the url?

Comment: return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <Root>
        <ErrorWrapper>
          <Countdown />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <Modals />
          <Notifications />
        </ErrorWrapper>
      </Root>
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
};

Comment: @brc-dd Root as a wrapper over the rest.How to write the code correctly using getServerSideProps to replace extra slashes in the url? Can you please an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request header modification (redirection) using `getServerSide` is not working due to some bug. Even if I define a route like `[...slug].js`, it is not being hit when there are two or more consecutive slashes. Try doing this using `next.config.js` instead:

```js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/(\\/{1,}):foo(.*)",
        destination: "/:foo",
        permanent: true
      },
      {
        source: "/:foo(.*?)(\\/{2,}):bar(.*)",
        destination: "/:foo/:bar",
        permanent: true
      }
    ];
  }
};
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-https-i1qjx?file=/next.config.js)

I don't have much experience with regexes, an expert will be able to combine these two rules.